# Incrementing Datetime field by one day in Elasticsearch Production Cluster using painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-painless

I am facing difficulty in debugging a production level Elastic Search Index Date time field in yyyy-MM-dd format & i want to update/increment the datetime field by one day Eg- 2009-07-01 i want to update it to 2009-07-02 for all the documents in the index.

I also want to know whether i have to use the re index api or update by query api

Currently i tried to update the document using following painless script its not working

```
POST klaprod-11042022/_update_by_query


{
  "script": {
    "source": "def df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd');def tmp = LocalDateTime.parse(ctx._source.debate_section_date,df);ctx._source.debate_section_date=tmp.plusDays(1);",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {"match_all":{}}
}
```

Any advise by the community is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the Documentation the following worked for me , you dont have to call the  `DateTimeFormatter` in painless as `LocalDate` can parse the date time string when in raw `yyyy-MM-dd` format

```
POST klaprod-11042022/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def tmp = LocalDate.parse(ctx._source.debate_section_date);ctx._source.debate_section_date=tmp.plusDays(1);",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {"match_all":{}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception because your date is not contaning any time. You need to use `atStartOfDay()` method of `LocalDate` to add one day.

```json
POST datecheck/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern('yyyy-MM-dd');def tmp = LocalDate.parse(ctx._source.date,df).atStartOfDay();ctx._source.date=tmp.plusDays(1);",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {"match_all":{}}
}
```

This will generate date with plus one date and add time as well. So if you not need time then you can again format date before setting to `ctx._source.date` field in script.

> I also want to know whether i have to use the re index api or update
> by query api

If you want to copy data to the new index then you can use `reindex` api otherwise `_update_by_query` will be used for same index update.

Comment: thanks for the answer , this didnt worked for me , i have posted my solution in the thread ,please give your observations